# Enum type naming conventions in DTO's

Tags: c#, .net, enums, domain-driven-design, dto

I'm creating an application facade in front of my domain model and using dto's for the exchanges between the consumer and the facade.

In order to avoid having to fully qualify my namespaces where I'm mapping between dto's and the domain model, I've suffixed all my dto's with Dto.   Ie.  CustomerDto, AddressDto etc.

I need to define an enum type as part of my dto's as well and am struggling with whether I should use the Dto suffix on my enum type.

I'm curious what others have done with enum types that reside in their dto's.   Any feedback is appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about an `enum` type when you say "enumeration," I wouldn't suffix it with Dto, since that's not really what it is. For example, I wouldn't say `CustomerTypeDto` since it's not a DTO representing a customer type. However, it is an `enum` representing the type for a `CustomerDto`, so maybe `CustomerDtoType` would be appropriate.

Comment: Yes, enum type is what I meant.   I do like your suggested convention.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would just use a seperate namepspace and the same name for the enumeration type.  I think it's important keep the two seperate so that the external one is just a use case projection of the model.

Comment: I definitely like keeping the two in separate namespaces, but I sort of dislike having them named the same when I'm mapping between the two.  Although, in this case adding dto to the name seems a bit odd as well.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the 'Dto' suffix for your domain model proxies, you could apply the same logic and use 'Enum' for your enums.

So for instance you'd have a 'CustomerDto' and 'CustomerTypeEnum'.

That's a question I just had in my current project and that's the solution I'm going to use.